# Feat that allows you to use your full strength modifier to offhand weapon damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, feats, two-weapon-fighting, content-identification

I seem to remember having seen a feat that allows you to use your full strength modifier when dealing damage with your offhand weapon when you two-weapon fight but I can't find it now, in Pathfinder 1e or D&D 3.5. Is there such a feat and if so, where can I find it?

Comment: Please clearly indicate which game you are playing because your question will be closed otherwise. Is it Pathfinder or D&D 3.5 which you are interested in?

Comment: @Anagkai The two systems are often played intermixed (and as I understand PF was in part designed with that in mind), so it's perfectly reasonable to not remember exactly which and thus ask for both.

Answer (score 14):

Welcome !
I think that the feat you are looking for, in Pathfinder 1e, comes from the Pathfinder RPG Core Rulebook :

[**Double Slice**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/double-slice-combat)

> Your off-hand weapon while dual-wielding strikes with greater power.
>
> *Prerequisite*: Dex 15, Two-Weapon Fighting.
>
> *Benefit*: Add your Strength bonus to damage rolls made with your off-hand weapon.
>
> *Normal*: You normally add only half of your Strength modifier to damage rolls made with a weapon wielded in your off-hand.